# Using mod_rewrite with CodeIgniter on Nearly Free Speech

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, nearlyfreespeech

I'll preface this by pointing out that I'm a massive noob with .htaccess stuff and server related stuff in general.

So I've built a website locally with wamp and I used a .htaccess file that I found from googling around.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my_project_folder_name/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I obviously replaced "my_project_folder_name" with the real folder name. This works perfectly on my local server. I decided to upload to site to my Nearly Free Speech server and I have been having some trouble with the mod_rewrite. I have no idea what I'm supposed to replace "my_project_folder_name" with, and I can't get it to work. I tried leaving it blank, and that worked, except for some reason this caused a bug that prevented POST data from being received by my scripts. Well, I'm assuming that's what caused the bug.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

For help purpose just check.

1. Check apache setting is rewrite_module setting is correct ?
2. if your folder name consist of two seperate words such as " XYZ ABC" then try " XYZ_ABC" and do the same with you .htaccess file.
3. Looking at the file it belongs to codeigniter (PHP FRAMEWORK). So if you are not using it then try to use..

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteBase /my_project_folder_name/
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
   </IfModule>
   ```

Hope your problem will get solved.. :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It turns out I was right leaving it blank, as the website is at the root, not in a subfolder like it is on wamp. So it would seem that the problem is an unwanted redirect when I submit the form, hence the no POST data.